# Is it possible/advisable to make the Sitecore CP accessible via sub-domain?

Tags: site-configuration

I want to know whether I can/should make `/sitecore` redirect to `sitecore.mysite.com`, and if so, how would I go about doing this?

I've figured out how to set up `sitecore.mysite.com`, and even have the shell and admin as `/shell` and `/admin` respectively, without the preceding `/sitecore` part. What I can't figure out is how to make the old links redirect to the sub-domain.

I also realized that the login page only works if it is `/sitecore/login`, and there may very well be other links that don't work properly.

Is any of this possible in Sitecore 9?

Comment: Why are you thinking changing sitecore url to sitecore.mysite.com? Do you have any particular reason?

Comment: Just a way to separate the admin controls from the main site. It’s common practice in some other content management systems and I’ve done this before with Sitecore 6.5, but for some reason I can’t figure out Sitecore 9.

Comment: I don't recommend/advise doing this in any context.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to set up my projects to support the desired functionality, though in a roundabout way. Basically, in the install script, I just set it up to install cms.sitename, then I modified the web.config to point the cms.sitename to the preview mode and added a new entry for www.sitename which points to the published site. The Sitecore panel is now accessible only from cms.sitename.

Also, to further clarify, this is on a local environment. As to the original question and the ability to drop `/sitecore` from the url, this does not seem possible or advisable, but is also not a concern since I was able to successfully set up the CM on a subdomain.

Comment: I would recommend adding screenshots and code snippets to create a more complete answer to your question.

Comment: For clarity, you are talking about LOCAL development, not a deployed environment?

Comment: For local environment, you only need to use the `Standalone` role.  However, what you asking, is instead of XP0 on your local, running XP1 (where CM and CD IIS instances are separated.